# How do I do a not equal in Django queryset filtering?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

In Django model QuerySets, I see that there is a `__gt` and `__lt` for comparative values, but is there a `__ne` or `!=` (**not equals**)? I want to filter out using a not equals. For example, for

```
Model:
    bool a;
    int x;
```

I want to do

```
results = Model.objects.exclude(a=True, x!=5)
```

The `!=` is not correct syntax. I also tried `__ne`.

I ended up using:

```
results = Model.objects.exclude(a=True, x__lt=5).exclude(a=True, x__gt=5)
```

Comment: Would results = Model.objects.exclude(a=true).filter(x=5) have worked?

Comment: @hughdbrown. No. Your query excludes all `a=true` first and then applies the `x=5` filter on the remaining. The intended query required only those with `a=true` and `x!=5`. The difference being that all those with `a=true` and `x=5` are also filtered out.

Answer (score 1093, accepted):

You can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) for this. They can be negated with the `~` operator and combined much like normal Python expressions:

```
from myapp.models import Entry
from django.db.models import Q

Entry.objects.filter(~Q(id=3))
```

will return all entries except the one(s) with `3` as their ID:

```
[<Entry: Entry object>, <Entry: Entry object>, <Entry: Entry object>, ...]
```

Comment: Is there any reason to do `Entry.objects.filter(~Q(id=3))` rather than `Entry.objects.exclude(id=3)`?

Comment: I suppose its use is conditional on the scenario, but Q objects allow for more complex queries. For example, you could string together the `~Q` query with other ones as well.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: @BobWhitelock: It's just a simple snippet for the question. In real world, much cases we have to use this. For example: EXCLUDE(A=1 and B__not=2); use extra .exclude is not right.

Comment: This makes sense... If you were to do a filtering in an annotation or aggregation, this would come in handy.

Comment: A typical use is to know if an object with a different parameter exists: `Entry.objects.filter(~Q(param="good")).exists()`

Comment: @echefede, exclude would also work in such a scenario

Answer (score 802):

Your query appears to have a double negative, you want to exclude all rows where `x` is not 5, so in other words you want to include all rows where `x` *is* 5. I believe this will do the trick:

```
results = Model.objects.filter(x=5).exclude(a=True)
```

To answer your specific question, there is no "not equal to" [field lookup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) but that's probably because Django has both [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) methods available so you can always just switch the logic around to get the desired result.

Comment: @d4nt: I may be wrong, but I think the query should be
`results = Model.objects.filter(a=true).exclude(x=5)`

Comment: @Taranjeet: I think you misread the original query. d4nt's version is correct, because OP wanted to exclude(a=True) and negate the exclusion of x=5 (i.e. include it).

Comment: I think this is wrong because an instance (x=4, a=false) would be wrongly excluded.

Comment: Just to say, the order matters so `objects.exclude(**filter1).filter(**filter2)` gives different results from `objects.filter(**filter1).exclude(**filter2)`, while ~Q will always get correct negation inside `objects.filter(**filter_with_Q)`

Comment: @danigosa That doesn't seem right. I just tried this myself, and the order of `exclude` and `filter` calls didn't make any meaningful difference. The order of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause changes, but how does that matter?

Comment: @danigosa order of exclude and filter doesn't matter.

Comment: This may fail if you are filtering on related object fields.

Comment: This answer is wrong. "you want to exclude all rows where x is not 5" - No, the asker wants to exclude rows where (x is not 5 **AND** a is True). 

     !(x != 5 AND a) 

iff. (!(x != 5) OR !a) [by De Morgan]

iff. (x == 5 OR !a)   [ by double negation]

But this solution provides all rows where 

(x == 5 AND !a)

Which is of course different in the cases where (x == 5 AND a) or when (x !=5 AND !a)

Answer (score 170):

the `field=value` syntax in queries is a shorthand for `field__exact=value`.  That is to say that [Django puts query operators on query fields in the identifiers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).  Django supports the following operators:

```
exact
iexact
contains
icontains
in
gt
gte
lt
lte
startswith
istartswith
endswith
iendswith
range

date
year
iso_year
month
day
week
week_day
iso_week_day
quarter
time
hour
minute
second

isnull
regex
iregex
```

I'm sure by combining these with the Q objects as [Dave Vogt suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering/1154977#1154977) and using `filter()` or `exclude()` as [Jason Baker suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering/687316#687316) you'll get exactly what you need for just about any possible query.

Comment: thanks this is awesome . i used some thing like this `tg=Tag.objects.filter(user=request.user).exclude(name__regex=r'^(public|url)$')` and it works.

Comment: @suhail, please mind that not all databases support that regex syntax :)

Comment: i in `icontains`, `iexact` and similar stands for "ignore case sensitivity". It is not for "inverse".

Comment: It is worth noting that when you are using `exclude()` with multiple terms, you may want to compose the proposition with the `OR` operator, e.g. `exclude(Q(field1__queryop1=value1) | Q(field2__queryop2=value2))` in order to exclude the results under both conditions.

Answer (score 160):

There are three options:

1. [Chain `exclude` and `filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

   ```
   results = Model.objects.exclude(a=True).filter(x=5)
   ```
2. Use [`Q()` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) and the [`~` operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

   ```
   from django.db.models import Q
   object_list = QuerySet.filter(~Q(a=True), x=5)
   ```
3. Register a [custom lookup function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-lookups/#a-lookup-example)

   ```
   from django.db.models import Lookup
   from django.db.models import Field

   @Field.register_lookup
   class NotEqual(Lookup):
       lookup_name = 'ne'

       def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
           lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
           rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
           params = lhs_params + rhs_params
           return '%s <> %s' % (lhs, rhs), params
   ```

   Which can the be used as usual:

   ```
   results = Model.objects.exclude(a=True, x__ne=5)
   ```

Comment: object_list = QuerySet.filter(~Q(a=True), x=5) : Remember to keep all the other conditions not containing Q after those containing Q.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann : A)you will then filter on a smaller set of data after exclusion using ~Q so is  more efficient. B) probably the sequencing the other way around does not work .. dun know .. dun remember!

Comment: wonder if there is a performance difference in 1 vs 2

Comment: NOTE: the `exclude` will add something to the WHERE clause, so it can be pretty efficient. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#exclude.  @Anupam

Answer (score 121):

It's easy to create a custom lookup, there's an `__ne` lookup example in [Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-lookups/#a-lookup-example).

You need to create the lookup itself first:

```
from django.db.models import Lookup

class NotEqual(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'ne'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return '%s <> %s' % (lhs, rhs), params
```

Then you need to register it:

```
from django.db.models import Field
Field.register_lookup(NotEqual)
```

And now you can use the `__ne` lookup in your queries like this:

```
results = Model.objects.exclude(a=True, x__ne=5)
```

Answer (score 55):

While you can filter Models with `=`, `__gt`, `__gte`, `__lt`, `__lte`, you cannot use `ne` or `!=`. However, you can achieve better filtering using the Q object.

You can avoid chaining `QuerySet.filter()` and `QuerySet.exclude()`, and use this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
object_list = QuerySet.filter(~Q(field='not wanted'), field='wanted')
```

Answer (score 30):

## Pending design decision. Meanwhile, use `exclude()`

The Django issue tracker has the remarkable [entry #5763](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5763),
titled *"Queryset doesn't have a "not equal" filter operator"*.
It is remarkable because (as of April 2016) it was 
"opened 9 years ago" (in the Django stone age),
"closed 4 years ago", and 
"last changed 5 months ago".

Read through the discussion, it is interesting.
Basically, some people argue `__ne` should be added
while others say `exclude()` is clearer and hence `__ne`
should *not* be added.

(I agree with the former, because the latter argument is
roughly equivalent to saying Python should not have `!=` because
it has `==` and `not` already...)

Comment: It's not a pending design decision, they decided to not do this 8 years ago.

Answer (score 25):

Using exclude and filter

```
results = Model.objects.filter(x=5).exclude(a=true)
```

Comment: How's this different from [@d4nt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139956) left 8 years before yours and [@outoftime's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778343) made 3 years before this one?

Answer (score 16):

You should use `filter` and `exclude` like this

```
results = Model.objects.exclude(a=true).filter(x=5)
```

Comment: How's this different from [@d4nt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139956) made 5 years before yours?

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy "edited Nov 12, 2020 at 7:03" you should be color blind or something.

Comment: If you click on "edited", you can see exactly what the person who edited the answer (it was me) changed, and you'll see that I fixed spelling mistakes and added links to documentation, otherwise the answer is the same as it was when it was posted in 2010.

Answer (score 10):

This will give your desired result.

```
from django.db.models import Q
results = Model.objects.exclude(Q(a=True) & ~Q(x=5))
```

for **not equal** you can use `~` on an equal query. obviously, `Q` can be used to reach the equal query.

Comment: Please check the edit; using “and” in `Q(a=True) and ~Q(x=5)` would evaluate to `~Q(x=5)` as arguments to `.exclude`. Please read: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations .

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for are all objects that have either `a=false` **or** `x=5`. In Django, `|` serves as `OR` operator between querysets:

```
results = Model.objects.filter(a=false)|Model.objects.filter(x=5)
```

Answer (score 8):

[Django-model-values](https://pypi.org/project/django-model-values/) (disclosure: author) provides an implementation of the [NotEqual](https://github.com/coady/django-model-values/blob/v0.5.1/model_values.py#L374) lookup, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29227603/36433).  It also provides syntactic support for it:

```
from model_values import F
Model.objects.exclude(F.x != 5, a=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work

```
results = Model.objects.filter(x=5).exclude(a=True)
```

Comment: This is the exact same code as [@d4nt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139956) from 12 years ago, [@outoftime's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778343) answer from 7 years ago and [@jincymariam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51303588) from 4 years ago.

Answer (score 7):

```
results = Model.objects.filter(a = True).exclude(x = 5)
```

Generetes this sql:

```
select * from tablex where a != 0 and x !=5
```

The sql depends on how your True/False field is represented, and the database engine. The django code is all you need though.

Answer (score 5):

The last bit of code will exclude all objects where x!=5 and a is True.  Try this:

```
results = Model.objects.filter(a=False, x=5)
```

Remember, the = sign in the above line is assigning False to the parameter a and the number 5 to the parameter x.  It's not checking for equality.  Thus, there isn't really any way to use the != symbol in a query call.

Comment: That isn't 100% the same thing since there could also be Null values for those fields.

Comment: This returns in only those items that have a=False _and_ x=5, but in the question an instance (a=false, x=4) would be included.

Comment: `results = Model.objects.filter(a__in=[False,None],x=5)`

Answer (score 2):

Watch out for lots of incorrect answers to this question!

Gerard's logic is correct, though it will return a list rather than a queryset (which might not matter).

If you need a queryset, use Q:

```
from django.db.models import Q
results = Model.objects.filter(Q(a=false) | Q(x=5))
```

Comment: "Gerard's [...] will return a list rather than a queryset" - that's not true. it returns a queryset. And your answer is the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to exclude/negate based on the sub queryset we can use,

[Conditional filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-filter):

When a conditional expression returns a boolean value, it is possible to use it directly in filters. Here `non_unique_account_type` returns a boolean value. But, still, we can use it in the filter.

```
>>> non_unique_account_type = Client.objects.filter(
...     account_type=OuterRef('account_type'),
... ).exclude(pk=OuterRef('pk')).values('pk')
>>> Client.objects.filter(~Exists(non_unique_account_type))
```

In the SQL terms, it evaluates to:

```
SELECT * FROM client c0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT c1.id
  FROM client c1
  WHERE c1.account_type = c0.account_type AND NOT c1.id = c0.id
)
```