# #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, select

I'm having trouble using a regular expression to select some results from my MySQL table.

I'm using this query

```
SELECT text 
FROM `articles` 
WHERE content REGEXP '.*<img.*?src=\"http://www' 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

And it says

```
#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

I tested the regex with Notepad++ and it works, why MySQL is giving me this error and how can i fix it?

Comment: This won't work well with any moderately sized tables.

Comment: @NullUserException I won't use this select more than once, i need this once to see which records in my table have absolute urls for images instead of relative urls and fix them, then i won't need it anymore

Comment: You can try `LIKE '%<img src="http://www%' `... Simpler

Comment: @ErickBest No. I don't know if i have `<img src="http://www` or `<img style="..." src="http://www"`, that's why i'm using a regex, i have to check the image source even if the `<img` tag contains other attributes before the `src` one

Answer (score 64, accepted):

According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

> MySQL uses Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions, which is aimed at conformance with POSIX 1003.2

[POSIX regexes](http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex) don't support using the question mark `?` as a non-greedy (lazy) modifier to the star and plus quantifiers like PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions). This means you can't use `+?` and `*?`

It looks like you'll just have to use the greedy version, which should still work. To avoid the matching of things like `<img style="/*some style*/" src="a.png"> <script src="www.example.com/js/abc.js">`, you can use a negated character class:

`'<img[^>]*src="http://www'`

Note: The `"` doesn't have to escaped and the `.*` at the beginning is implied.

Comment: That doesn't work. if i have `<img style="/*some style*/" src="a.png"> <script src="http://www.example.com/js/abc.js">` it would return me that row, which is wrong.

Comment: +1 - Never use `.*` when a more precise expression can be crafted, i.e. `[^>]*`

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
SELECT 
        text 
        , 
     IF (content LIKE '%<img src="http://%', text  , content LIKE '%<img style=%') 
as imageText

FROM    articles ORDER BY date DESC
```

This will Check first for where content has `<img src="http://` if it can't find then it will look for `<img style=` instead.

Hope it Helps.

Check Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a2f0/13/0

Comment: Why the _DownVote_?...Please leave a comment if your _DownVote_ is genuine... Peace!!