# mysql regex error #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, error-handling, regexp-replace

I'm using a custom regex replace method found [here](https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/).
I put in my own method

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_text` 
 SET `attribute_id` = regex_replace('^[^.]*^(.*?)\:', '<b>^[^.]*^(.*?)\:</b>', attribute_id)
```

But when I run this the database gives me the error;

> Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

It says in the documentation in the link above that the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode must be set to ON but I'm not sure if this is the issue or how to do this.
I have MySQL 5.5.

Comment: may i know what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this may be helpful for you     [click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18317617/5010527

Comment: Try `regex_replace('^([^.]*)(.*?):', '\\1<b>\\2</b>:', attribute_id)`. This should enclose the text matched with `(.*?)` in b tags.