# Regular Expressions (without "?") to match line that doesn't contain specific string (error #1139)

Tags: php, mysql, regex

**I need**: a regexp for MySQL (php, PDO) usage. Regexp should find all numbers between brackets [ ], except number 150.

So I would like to get:

```
[3]
[25464]
[510]
```

But I would like to exclude:

```
[150]
```

**What I got:**

```
\[{1}((?!150)[0-9])+\]{1}
```

and it works fine for newest version of MySQL, but I need something that would work also on an older version (probably 5.1).

**Problem**: Currently I get an error:

```
1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

I know I can't use ?. How can I replace it?

Additional info (edit):
*I'm redesigning the database and that's why I need to write this*

II edit - why I need this:
I need to retrieve all rows which in column "content" contains **only one** specified [150]. One column 'content' can contain zero [nr] or one specific [nr] or many different [nrs].

```
WHERE content REGEXP '\[{1}((?!150)[0-9])+\]{1}' = 0 AND content LIKE '%[150]%'
```

Comment: You need to redesign your database.

Comment: You [can't use a lookahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317183/1139-got-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-from-regexp). Try [`\[([0-9]{1,2}|[02-9][0-9]{2}|[0-9][0-46-9][0-9]|[0-9]{2}[1-9]|[0-9]{4,})]`](https://regex101.com/r/cH6jS9/1)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yep, and that's why I'm writing this regexp.

Comment: Can you show us the actual _records_ which contain these numbers?  Perhaps you can get away without using `REGEXP()`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I use this regexp to search within text (text column in db). This column contains text from blog, with html tags etc. Is this information sufficient for you?

Comment: What I'm thinking is maybe you could use clever string manipulation to get what you need without resorting to an ugly regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I saw this and it doesn't contain answer to my problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to find all records which contain in column 'content' at least one [number]. If nr [150] exists in this column even once, I would like to exclude this record. Column 'content' can have many numbers between brackets (in one record), or not have them at all. I change nr 150 in a loop (it's flexible). I'm not sure if I can skip regexp usage but I'm open to any proposal :)

Comment: MySQL is not well-suited to handle this problem.  As others have said, you should either redesign your database, or do the heavy lifting in your app PHP code.

Comment: I've already wrote it: **I'm redesigning the database and that's why I need to write this.**

Comment: Minus 1 without a feedback = -10 for the author. It's clearly written question, as far as I know it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @suz I think the downvote comes because you haven't clearly posted a set of content rows (the actual values) that accurately articulates the issue, nor an expected output for that input.  I would like to help resolve this old abandoned question.  I have a potential non-regex solution but I want to be sure I understand your question.  Can you update your question? and then ping me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, Hope this works.

```
 $string='[3]
 [25464]
 [510]
 [150]
 [100]';
 preg_match_all('/\[(?!150)\d+\]/', $string,$matches);
 print_r($matches);
```

This will match all digits(except 150) with brackets.
**$matches[0]** will contain desired result...

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but I need something which I can use inside a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE     x REGEXP '\[[[:digit:]]+\]'
  AND NOT x REGEXP '\[150\]'
```

However, that will reject `aaa[123]bbb[150]ccc`.  Should it be rejected?  (Please give some sample data that be matched / rejected.  Your goal is not crystal clear.)

Since `LIKE` is faster than `REGEXP`, this will be a little faster:

```
WHERE x REGEXP '\[[[:digit:]]+\]'
  AND x NOT LIKE '%[150]%'
```