# Error when using REGEXP in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Error when using `REGEXP` in `mysql` -  REG#1139 -

> Got error 'this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0'

from regexp in `xampp` `ubuntu`, 
PHP Version 5.6.15
mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503

Comment: Please post some of your code please.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317183/1139-got-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-from-regexp)

Comment: Have a look at this : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=106313

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same error after an upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

I'm using lampp 5.6.20 and had the same error in the requests using REGEXP.

With the below command, I detected this lib doens't have UTF-8 support:

```
$ /opt/lampp/bin/pcretest -C

...
No UTF-8 support
...
```

I found that I must recompile my lampp PCRE with these options:

```
--enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties
```

To do that I downloaded pcre-8.38 and in the extracted folder I executed the next command:

```
$ ./configure --enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Then I copied all generated files in the `.libs` folder to the `/opt/lampp/lib` folder :

```
$ sudo cp .libs/* /opt/lampp/lib
```

Then confirmed support for UTF-8:

```
$ /opt/lampp/bin/pcretest -C

...
UTF-8 support
...
```

Lastly I restarted my lampp (to restart mysql or MariaDB) :

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Comment: This worked for me. Only problem I had was that I had to restart lampp twice for some reason. This should be accepted as the right answer.