# MySQL regular expression to Count How many number of digits are in the username (String)?

Tags: php, mysql

I need a MySQL regular expression to count the number of digits in the user's user name.

**i.e. if it has more than 7 numbers needs to be selected.**

I tried following expression but it gives me error

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `name` REGEXP '^\D*(?:\d\D*){7,}$'
```

Error i get is

**#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp**

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18317617/ might shed some light on this (the question mark) and the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: See also this note in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html): "Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in your REGEXP strings."

Comment: Maybe you could extract numbers [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query#answer-991802) and check if number is greater than 999999 (or something similar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `\d` and `\D` and `(?:)` syntax but MySQL doesn't support those extended regular expression metacharacters.

> If it has more than 7 numbers it need to be selected.

So I would guess you can assume the username is valid, i.e. you don't need to check that it starts with a non-digit. And you might accept a username that has more than 7 digits as well as at least 7 digits. I'm also assuming the digits don't need to be together, there just have to be 7 of them.

Here's a regexp that works:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `name` REGEXP '([[:digit:]].*){7}';
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use `[^[:digit:]]*` instead of `.*` to prevent catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Good idea @Barmar!