# #1139 repetition-operator operand invalid REGEXP MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

why does the following regex give me the infamous 1139 error?

```
IF NEW.`Email` REGEXP "/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i" THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10002'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid email';
END IF
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317183/1139-got-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-from-regexp)

Comment: I really have no clue what that entire article says. Do I just need to replace every `?` with a `*`?

Comment: "POSIX regexes don't support using the question mark ? as a non-greedy (lazy) modifier to the star and plus quantifiers like PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions). This means you can't use +? and *?"

Comment: @Adam No. You're going to have to study it until you understand the topic. Some work required.

Comment: Would replacing the `+?` and `*?` with simple `*` work?

Comment: MySQL (before 8.0) has a rather limited REGEXP.  Many constructs in what you have will fail.  MariaDB 10 does much better.