# Mysql error " repetition-operator operand invalid"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting a strange mysql error that I've never really seen before. 
It's caused by a query similar to the one below. 
Any advice?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE col REGEXP '^* MAN *$'  
 LIMIT 100
```

Error:

```
#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

-- UPDATE --

Ok I can confirm that the following two solutions worked. Thanks to the help of both answers below:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE col REGEXP '^(\\*) MAN (\\*)$'  
 LIMIT 100

SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE col REGEXP '^[*] MAN [*]$'  
 LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Similar? Does the above query have the problem or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317183/1139-got-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-from-regexp)

Comment: what is the string you are trying to match???

Comment: What is the purpose of `^*`, Did you mean `^.*` because the first one reads to me as one or more start of line

Comment: @nikhilsugandh I'm trying to match the string "* MAN *" as an exact match But to cut a log story short i need to use regex. And im needing something like "^\* MAN \*$". But thats the error I get above regardless of escaping

Comment: @Jens yeah I looked into this question yesterday but didn't seem to be that helpful for me. I need to use regex. It can't be a like. It's a long story but regex is the most reliable results we've had in our use case. But just incase the user puts in these type of chars I need to find out how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE col REGEXP '.* MAN .*' ` or `WHERE col REGEXP '^.* MAN .*$'`?

Comment: What is the reason for using such regular expression? Give data example.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson hi there. the * need to be treated as a char not regex. like \* but i still get the same problems

Comment: `'^\* MAN \*$'` for a literal string, actually resulting in **equality**: `col = '* MAN *'` (apart from case insensitive comparison).

Comment: show us your sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\  and * itself are metacharacters thats why * is to be followed by two \ so that  seconod \ is also not considered as a a literal but metacharactcer

this will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE column1 RLIKE '(\\*)(man)(\\*)';
```

see link its working now:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e695cf/1/0

Comment: you have to use escape character to amtch it wiht * like this:  `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col,'^(\*)(MAN){1}(\*)$')`

Comment: I tried "WHERE col REGEXP '^(\*)(MAN)(\*)$'  " and I get the following error " Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp"

Comment: Yeah I got this error " FUNCTION database.REGEXP_LIKE does not exist"

Comment: just got this error: "Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184865/discussion-between-nikhil-sugandh-and-theman68).

Comment: Hi great. Yeah that doesn't break the query but it also doesn't find any results when there is one in the db

Comment: Ah my bad. I had spaces but there were no spaces in the regex. it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you want to match 'bla bla * MAN *bla bla' for instance

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col REGEXP '[*] MAN [*]'
```

If you want to match '* MAN *'

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col REGEXP '^[*] MAN [*]$'
```

or without regexp

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col ='* MAN *'
```