# MySQL regex to match and not match multiple expressions regardless of order

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a REGEX to match the following 3 input strings:

```
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=1
propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE&city=1
city=1&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE
city=1&serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE
serviceType=SALE
```

and not match

```
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=2
propertyType=HOUSE&city=2&serviceType=SALE
city=2&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=FARM&city=1
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=UNIT
serviceType=RENTAL&propertyType=HOUSE
serviceType=RENTAL
```

I tried the following which matches the first input string but couldn't figure out the rest:

```
(?=.*serviceType=SALE)(?=.*propertyType=HOUSE)(?=.*city=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for something like this:

```
^serviceType=SALE(?:&propertyType=HOUSE(?:&city=1)?)?$
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/a0HN2s/1) for a demo

**EDIT**

If the order of parameters is not important, then use this regex:

```
^(?:(?:&|^)(?:serviceType=SALE|propertyType=HOUSE|city=1)){1,3}$
```

It means "a `&` or start of the string (`^`), which is followed by any of the three parameters, all repeated 1 to 3 times.

See new [demo](https://regex101.com/r/a0HN2s/3).

If you are searching this pattern within an URL, I guess you should replace the initial `^` with `(?:^|(?<=\?))` for stating that the string can also be preceded by a question mark.

Comment: hi @horcrux, the above regex doesn't work in MySQL unfortunately. The error I am getting is "Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp". The reason is explained in details  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317183/1139-got-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-from-regexp). Could you please help?

Comment: There is no lazy operator in the above regex. I guess you just have to remove `?:`

Comment: thanks @horcrux, I've checked the pattern to select query from search s where s.query regexp '^((&|^)(serviceType=SALE|propertyType=HOUSE|city=1)){1,3}$'
which still works in the regex tester but returns no matches in MySQL. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: I don't see any error. Are you sure the input is like `serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=1` or it is a full url? Be aware this regex won't work if there are other characters near the string.

Comment: all good, it was my bad.. I copy/paste the code directly to the table field instead of running insert statement. All good and working fine. Thanks again @horcrux