# REGEX alternative

Tags: mysql, regex

Any guy can find the alternative way to rewrite the 2 REGEXs below without the question mark (?).

```
^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}$
^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$
```

Or, can you suggest how to make a query for search VISA and JCB card pattern with SQL language.

I just want to make a query to search card pattern inside my database. I try to use the regular expression to done this. Unfortunately, POSIX regexes don't support using the question mark `?` as a non-greedy (lazy) modifier to the star and plus quantifiers like PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions). This means you can't use `+?` and `*?`.

Comment: Without question mark? What do you mean. You want to get rid of the non-capturing group or the optional non-capturing group. I'd say there is a huge question mark over your question you need to get rid of first =)

Comment: What SQL RDBMS are you usin? T-SQL? Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: @JvdV I just want to make a query to search card pattern inside my database. I try to use the regular expression to done this. Unfortunately, POSIX regexes don't support using the question mark ? as a non-greedy (lazy) modifier to the star and plus quantifiers like PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions). This means you can't use +? and *? [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317183/1139-got-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-from-regexp). So, I try to find another ways to search it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew MySQL

Comment: Then all you need is replace `(?:` with `(` and replace `\d` with `[0-9]`. You have no `*?` nor `+?` in your regexes. `^(2131|1800|35[0-9]{3})[0-9]{11}$` and `^4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great job!. It's work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL versions before v.8, you need to use POSIX ERE like regex syntax, that is:

- You can't use non-capturing groups
- You can't use `\d` shorthand character class for digits, you need to use `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`
- You won't be able to use lazy quantifiers, but your patterns do not contain them. In some cases, they can be replaced with negated bracket expressions (e.g. `a.*?b` is better written as `a[^ab]*b`).

In your case, you need to replace `(?:` with `(` and replace `\d` with `[0-9]`

```
^(2131|1800|35[0-9]{3})[0-9]{11}$
^4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?$
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor Stribiżew, I'm back again for request your help. Could you please make this REG-EX "^65[4-9][0-9]{13}|64[4-9][0-9]{13}|6011[0-9]{12}|(622(?:12[6-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-8][0-9][0-9]|9[01][0-9]|92[0-5])[0-9]{10})$" to suitable with MySQL search pattern. Thankss

Comment: @WICHPONGKAO-IAN See *You can't use non-capturing groups*. Replace all `(?:` with `(`.

Comment: Is result of searching is same with `(?:`  ?

Comment: @WICHPONGKAO-IAN Since there are no inline backreferences, sure

Comment: Thanks =/\= @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score -1):

You drop the question mark in `(?:` that makes it a normal group.

instead of the `)?` use `){0,1}`