# Search MySQL database tables for URLs

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to search a table for `text` column that contains a URL. So I used this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text REGEXP '((http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?)'
```

But I get this error below

> #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

I need to get rows that the `text` column contains a URL string, something like this:

```
"Hello http://www.google.com World http://examples.com"
```

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317183/1139-got-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-from-regexp

Comment: You do not need that big pattern to check if there is a URL, try something like `'(http|ftp)s?://'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but when a text has something like this `No john don't use http:// use https:// instead` it doesn't contain a URL but its going to be selected... Please can u show me a proper way of making sure the selected text has a URL?

Comment: I think it is still something like `'(http|ftp)s?://[^/[:space:]]+\\.[[:alpha:]]+'`

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (8.0 changed the syntax.)

Comment: I'm using version 7

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ver%';` -- There is no MySQL version 7.  Maybe 5.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
REGEXP '(http|ftp)s?://[^/[:space:]]+\\.[[:alpha:]]+'
```

The pattern means:

- `(http|ftp)` - either `http` or `ftp`
- `s?` - an optional `s`
- `://` - a `://` string
- `[^/[:space:]]+` - one or more chars other than `/` and whitespace
- `\\.` - a `.` (it is in fact `\.` text)
- `[[:alpha:]]+`  - one or more letters.

Answer (score -1):

When including a dash in a character class, beware.  It has special meaning.

```
[\w_-]
```

-->

```
[-\w_]
```

Dash is not special in the first position, so it will work as just another character.

If you are using 8.0, double up any backslashes.

```
[-\\w_]
```