# Why doesn't the django queryset contains work for me?

Tags: python, django

I should be able to use the queryset '_contains' on my Django object variables to filter my results, according to [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

But when I implement this code:

`cookbooks = Books.objects.filter (category_contains = 'cooking')`

I get the following error:

`Cannot resolve keyword 'category_contains' into field. Choices are: category, adder, date etc.`

Why is this happening? I also saw [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering/1154977#1154977) where someone explains that just using variable `category` implies `category_exact`. But if I write `category_exact` I get a similar error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a double underscore `__` not a single underscore `_`.

Comment: Oh you're right. While playing around I changed some other stuff. That did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Field lookups are prefixed via two underscores (`__`) not one (`_`).  It can be hard to tell the difference at first when you are not familiar with the syntax.

Double check the documentation for [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4) in general and more specifically the [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-contains) documentation.  Here is the example from the contains documentation with comments showing one or two underscores:

```
Entry.objects.get(headline__contains='Lennon')
#                         __ <-- 2 _'s
#                     not _  <-- 1 _
```

Comment: The solution for me was your `=`. Note, that Django gives `NameError` on `Entry.objects.get(headline__contains('Lennon'))`, telling that the `headline__contains` name is not defined. But **change parentheses to =** and the NamError goes away.