# How do I change the filter in django to reflect not equal to?

Tags: django, view, filter, equals

I have the following filter:

```
open_slots = Opening.objects.filter(club_id=club_id, day=datetime.date.today(), reservation ='Open')
```

I want to create another list "closed_slots" that has all the same attributes as the above except that reservation is not equal to 'Open'.  When I tried using reservation !='Open' I get an error.  How do I fix this?

Comment: For fine-grained control on the returned set, look at Django's ORM docs, specifically on using [`.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Comment: You can also negate a query - see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `exclude` method. Details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/).

```
open_slots = Opening.objects.filter(club_id=club_id, day=datetime.date.today()).exclude(reservation ='Open')
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried with following and it's working fine.

```
from django.db.models import Q
open_slots = Opening.objects.filter(~Q(reservation ='Open'),club_id=club_id, day=datetime.date.today() )
```