# Getting all objects of model except

Tags: django, django-models

Let the models class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to get all the objects of `MyModel` except those with a specific category. I'm using this code:

```
[mm for mm in MyModel.objects.all() if mm.category != u'mycategory']
```

Is there another solution for this question?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering

Comment: actually I think it is a simpler, clearer example for when to use exclude, the other question is a bit more complex on the face of it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters , you want to use an exclude filter.

So somethig like:

```
objects = MyModel.objects.exclude(category= u'mycategory')
```