# Function of pub_date__gte=datetime.now

Tags: python, django

```
>>> Entry.objects.filter(
...     headline__startswith='What'
... ).exclude(
...     pub_date__gte=datetime.now()
... ).filter(
...     pub_date__gte=datetime(2005, 1, 1)
... )
```

*"This takes the initial QuerySet of all entries in the database, adds a filter, then an exclusion, then another filter. The final result is a QuerySet containing all entries with a headline that starts with “What”, that were published between January 1, 2005, and the current day."*

Can someone explain what is the __ and the word gte doing in this context. I cannot visualize how the above query extracts the range between January 1, 2005, and the current day since we are excluding datetime.now . I am sure it is relating to something that I am missing regarding the double underscore and gte. Thanks.

Comment: `pub_date__gte` == "Publication Date greater than or equal". Doesn't seem to make much sense to exclude posts from the future though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__gte` just means "Greater than or equal" operator, this is just a special syntax for making `WHERE` clauses. There are others, like `__gt`, `__lt`, `__lte`, `__startswith` etc. See more info in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

`exclude()` is just an opposite to `filter`, quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters):

> `filter(**kwargs)`
>
> Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match
>   the given lookup parameters.
>
> `exclude(**kwargs)`
>
> Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that do not match the given lookup parameters.

So, the code you've provided is actually saying:

give me all entries, where:

- `headline` starts with `What` and
- `pub_date` is **not** greater than or equal to current date and
- `pub_date` is greater than or equal to `1/1/2005`

Also see:

- [How do I do a not equal in Django queryset filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering)