# Django Json Field - Find objects hat do not have key

Tags: python, django, django-postgresql

I have a Model with a JSON Field.

```
data = JSONField(default=dict)
```

Is there an efficient way - or queryset filter -  to find all instances of this Model that do not have a speicfic key in the json field.

Django documentation includes [has_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#has-key) function for JSON field.

Essentially i'm looking for a way to do not_has_key

My current method:

```
queryset = MyObj.objects.all()
for obj in queryset:
    if 'my_key' not in obj.data:
        do_work()
    else:
        pass
        #key_already_exists
```

Many thanks

Comment: I believe that's the most pythonic way to check if a key in (or in your case, is not) in a dictionary.

Comment: another way is using the ~Q operator [Q operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154977/11225821)

Comment: If you don't want to iterate through them all and just get a collection of instances that *do not have the key* then use `exclude` with `has_key`: e.g. `SomeModel.objects.exclude(jsonfield__has_key='field_name')`