# How to solve cannot unpack non-iterable bool object error in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

if i put below condition in my view file

```
 id=request.POST['id'] #post data which i am sending from html file
 name=request.POST['name'] #post data which i am sending from html file

 if MyModel.objects.filter(id=id,name!=name).exists():
   print('data available')
 else:
   print('data is not available')
```

its showing below error

```
cannot unpack non-iterable bool object
```

if `request.POST['name']` is available in my requested id(`request.POST['id']`),then i want to print `print('data available')`. Otherwise i want to print `print('data is not available')` How to Do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do a not equal in Django queryset filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering)

Comment: or, `MyModel.objects.filter(id=id).exclude(name=name).exists()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
results = Model.objects.exclude(name=name).filter(id=id)
```