# Performance: Django postgresql query stuck when searching on negative condition

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have this class name:
Maybe it is the

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    language = models.ManyToManyField(
        "instagram_data.Language", verbose_name=_("language_code_name"), blank=True)
```

```
class Language(models.Model):
    code_name = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code_name
```

While searching for specific name it return values fast (few sec), (i.g **Follower_obj.language.code_name = "he"**):
[he lang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o7LK.png)

While adding the check for **Follower_obj.language.code_name != "ar"**, it can take few minutes !

Maybe design issue ?

**EDIT:**
Running Explain:
So I first minimized the queryset by filter _is_verified than run the slow language check:

```
        qs1 = Follower.objects.filter(Q(is_verified=True))
        print(qs1.explain())

        qs2 = qs1.filter(~Q(language__code_name='ar'))
        print(qs2.explain())
```

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..1216249.91 rows=7960 width=979)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on instagram_data_follower  (cost=0.00..1214453.91 rows=3317 width=979)
        Filter: is_verified
Gather  (cost=6135.18..92362779347.15 rows=3980 width=979)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on instagram_data_follower  (cost=5135.18..92362777949.15 rows=1658 width=979)
        Filter: (is_verified AND (NOT (SubPlan 1)))
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Materialize  (cost=5135.18..56725.50 rows=157291 width=4)
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5135.18..55324.05 rows=157291 width=4)
                      ->  Seq Scan on instagram_data_language u2  (cost=0.00..1.64 rows=1 width=4)
                            Filter: ((code_name)::text = 'ar'::text)
                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on instagram_data_follower_language u1  (cost=5135.18..53615.64 rows=170677 width=8)
                            Recheck Cond: (language_id = u2.id)
```

SQL EXECUTED:

```
SELECT * FROM "instagram_data_follower" WHERE NOT ("instagram_data_follower"."id" IN (SELECT U1."follower_id" FROM "instagram_data_follower_language" U1 INNER JOIN "instagram_data_language" U2 ON (U1."language_id" = U2."id") WHERE U2."code_name" = ar)))
```

What am I see here?

EDIT:

Lookup is faster by searching id in Follower instead of char. but still not fast as I want it to be.
Not sure what "not-equal" best design optimization is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get SQL explanation for your queries, look at this pseudocode:

```
qs1 = (Follower_obj.language.code_name = "he")
qs1.explain()

qs2 = (Follower_obj.language.code_name != "ar")
qs2.explain()
```

see [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) for info. Possibly you might need `.prefetch_related('language')` optimization, but [better check Django DB optimization docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/optimization/) first.

Comment: Added Explain results

Comment: Now we can see the nested loop that's perfect for a bottleneck. Since there are only a few languages they could be prefetched to optimize the nested loops. Also you should try to get that_language_id for "ar" and then run `qs1.filter(~Q(language_id=that_language_id))` to avoid joining the tables and getting the loops.

Comment: @frost-nzcr4 how do we get the id out of the name ? where is it stored ?
And let me get it - the issue is that each query need to check the != to the char 'ar' so it need to retrieve the language object each time for each row and check the char? why is it different from == isn't that the same case?
print(Language.objects.all())
return

Comment: print(Language.objects.all())
return
<QuerySet [<Language: he>, <Language: ar>, <Language: en>,
  so 'ar' is 1 ?

Comment: Is your Language table has only unique languages? Because code_name doesn't primary key or unique it could not be optimized for scan. An id field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields is created automatically by Django and you can get optimization using it in filter. Try primary_key=True or uniqie=True.

Comment: Is your Language table has only unique languages? YES I guess I can summarize to 130 options.
But unique will leave me with 1 language per followers no ?

will the search for id instead of char_code for sure make it faster ? since I still see slow search

Comment: Please see sql executed. I think the id is not the issue

Comment: You have select within select. Try to optimize it with `distinct` to avoid follower_id duplications. Some RDBMS have optimizations for nested selects but for the short one like 10, 100, maybe 1000 rows, but when you go through that boundaries the nested select will be triggered on each row.

Comment: To avoid this you might create temporary table with only followers without "ar" language like this `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS followers_without_ar_language AS (SELECT DISTINCT idfl.follower_id
FROM instagram_data_follower_language idfl
INNER JOIN "instagram_data_language" idl ON idl.id = idfl.language_id
WHERE idl.code_name != "ar"
GROUP BY idfl.follower_id`) and then LEFT JOIN instagram_data_follower to each row. This kind of magic possible via raw Django queries https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/

Comment: How do I add a custom SQL to django admin is it only in get_queryset function ?

Comment: It's worth asking a new question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Q objects for this. They can be negated with the ~ operator and combined much like normal Python expressions:

```
from django.db.models import Q
objs = Language.objects.filter(~Q(code_name = 'ar' ))
```

more info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering)

Comment: This is not the Quastion - the issue is performance - search is very very slow!