# Django NotEqual custom lookup on related field

Tags: python, django

I registered a custom lookup base on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687295/how-do-i-do-a-not-equal-in-django-queryset-filtering/29227603#answer-35603223) and official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-lookups/#a-lookup-example).

```
# core/custom_lookup.py

from django.db.models import Lookup


class NotEqual(Lookup):
    """Missing != operator."""
    lookup_name = 'ne'

    def as_sql(self, *args):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(*args)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(*args)
        return '{} <> {}'.format(lhs, rhs), lhs_params + rhs_params
```

I registered the custom lookup in my app config.

```
# core/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models import Field
from .custom_lookup import NotEqual


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'core'

    def ready(self):
        Field.register_lookup(NotEqual)
```

Then i use it in the exclude method this way.

```
Customer.objects.all().filter(filter).exclude(private=True, user__ne=info.context.user).order_by('-created')
```

The idea here is to get all the customers where **user** is info.context.user (with **private** is **False** or **True**) **OR** **user** is **NOT** info.context.user but **private** is **False** but **exclude** customers where **user** is **NOT** info.context.user **AND** **private** is **True**

But whenever I play the query the error below is thrown

> Related Field got invalid lookup: ne

Am I missing something on the registration of the lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bit explored and found the way.
You should add Related field lookup because user is ForeignKey or OneToOneField I guess,
So the code is,

##### core/custom_lookup.py

```
from django.db.models import Lookup
from django.db.models.fields.related_lookups import RelatedLookupMixin

class NotEqual(Lookup):
    """Missing != operator."""
    lookup_name = 'ne'

    def as_sql(self, *args):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(*args)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(*args)
        return '{} <> {}'.format(lhs, rhs), lhs_params + rhs_params

class NotEqualRelated(RelatedLookupMixin, Lookup):
    """Missing != operator."""
    lookup_name = 'nere'

    def as_sql(self, *args):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(*args)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(*args)
        return '{} <> {}'.format(lhs, rhs), lhs_params + rhs_params
```

##### core/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models import Field
from .custom_lookup import NotEqual, NotEqualRelated
from django.db.models.fields.related import RelatedField, OneToOneField

class MainConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'main'

    def ready(self):
        Field.register_lookup(NotEqual)
        OneToOneField.register_lookup(NotEqualRelated)
```

In your case you may need to add *ForeignKey.register_lookup* .
please take a try this code and let me know if you face any issues.

**2nd solution:**

We can use a field lookup argument "__" so that we can compare the id of the foreign object (user) to another id (user from context in this case).

```
Customer.objects.all().filter(filter).exclude(private=True, user__id__ne=info.context.user.id).order_by('-created')
```

Comment: Indeed it is because of the foreign key. Also another solution was to update the query with user__id__ne=info.context.user.id

Comment: Your solution is very simple. Thanks for the information.